# How to delete object assigned to variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, del

I have the following code:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, item):
    self.item = item  

node1 = Node(12)
cur = node1
```

Is it possible to delete `node1`using `cur`?

I tried `del cur` but it doesn't give the desired outcome `cur` now no longer exists but `node1` still does.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Also, if you delete `node1` the `Node` instance will not be removed from memory. It will eventually be removed by the garbage collection if there are no other references to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clear a misconception: objects are not "assigned" in Python.

Variables are merely a reference to a location in memory that happens to contain values.

By doing `del cur` you are only making sure that `cur` does not reference the memory location that `node1` also refers to, but nothing will happen to `node1`.

Check out this [visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20Node%3A%0A%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20item%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20self.item%20%3D%20item%20%20%0A%0Anode1%20%3D%20Node%2812%29%0Acur%20%3D%20node1%0Adel%20cur&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false). Note how both `node1`'s and `cur`'s arrows point to the same `Node` object's location in memory. If you click on "Forward" you will see that when `del cur` is executed the only thing that happens is that `cur`'s arrow will be removed (ie `cur` will no longer reference the same location in memory that `node1` references).

There is no way to do the same for `node1` without doing `del node1`, and even then it is up to the garbage collector to decide when to delete the `Node` object itself (which will actually free up the memory it takes). This depends on the specific implementation of the Python interpreter, but this is usually done with reference-counting.

See these 2 off-site resources for useful info:

[Python's garbage collector](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/) and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 3):

in addition to DeepSpace answer, there is no way to delete `node1` except that you find all variables that refer to that instance, then delete it, I came up with a function to use instead of `del` for your purpose:

```
import sys

def kill(name):
    l = []
    for k, v in sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.items():
        if str(v) == str(name):  # Finding all vars that refers to that instace
            l.append(k)

    for i in l:  # Deleting them
        del sys.modules[__name__].__dict__[i]
```

so, if you have this class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item  

node1 = Node(12)
cur = node1
```

if you type:

```
kill(cur)
```

`node1` and all of the others that is referring to that instance will be deleted.

testing:

```
In [116]: node1
Out[116]: <__main__.Node at 0x7f68eca386d8>

In [117]: cur
Out[117]: <__main__.Node at 0x7f68eca386d8>

In [118]: kill(cur)

In [119]: cur
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-3c1cfaee77de> in <module>()
----> 1 cur

NameError: name 'cur' is not defined

In [120]: node1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-d9e9a8ca6efc> in <module>()
----> 1 node1

NameError: name 'node1' is not defined
```